# Retrofit 2: Gradle Build error

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

This is currently my build configuration of retrofit 2 for gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'
```

As everyone knows retrofit 2 is out of beta I am trying to upgrade with it to newer version which follows as below

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
```

I am unable to build my gradle I get exception while building gradle as javacIllegalArgumentException

Comment: This combination of retrofit dependencies is perfectly fine (except, that there is newer version of `logging-interceptor`). The error must be somewhere else. Post Messages ouput.

Comment: @R.Zagórski   its like this Execution failed for the task ':app:compileDevReleaseJavaWithJavac' > java.lang.illegalArgumentException:(java.lang.String)<any>

Comment: Probably the definition of one function changed with the newer version of Retrofit.

Comment: @R.Zagórski  Any solution how to resolve this

Comment: Look into the code, what function has changed. The build error must lead to a line in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try mavenCentral instead jcenter in 'build.gradle':

```
repositories {
    //jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
```